# Les sous-subordonnées héritent-elles du mode subjonctif ?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, subordonnées, mode-grammatical

Prenons comme exemple *j'ai peur que*, qui est suivi du subjonctif, et *il pense que*, qui seul et sans négation est suivi de l'indicatif :

> J'ai peur que son interlocuteur ait pour dessein de l'énerver.
>
> Il pense que son interlocuteur a pour dessein de l'énerver.

Lorsqu'on imbrique *penser que* dans *avoir peur que*, le subjonctif peut(doit ?)-il être utilisé dans la subordonnée de second niveau ?

> J’ai peur qu’il pense que son interlocuteur __ pour dessein de l'énerver.

Je suis intéressé par le cas général (non nécessairement restreint à ces deux constructions) et à la recherche de références grammaticales ou/et statistiques.

Comment: Une autre question semblable a été posée récemment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46676/je-d%c3%a9teste-penser-que-subjonctif . Il est dit que le subjonctif rajoute une "possibilité", qui n'est pas nécessairement "peu probable" comme dans la réponse ici.

Answer (score 4):

Dans votre exemple

*J'ai peur qu'il pense que son interlocuteur [avoir] pour dessein de l'énerver*

il convient de décortiquer les propositions et de trouver qui est subordonné à qui.

La partie *"qu'il pense que son interlocuteur [avoir] pour dessein de l'énerver"* est subordonnée à *"j'ai peur"*, et demande donc un subjonctif, comme vous le disiez. Ce subjonctif est *"qu'il pense"*, ce qui est trompeur dans l'exemple puisque le subjonctif du verbe du premier groupe ressemble à la conjugaison indicative.
Choisissons un autre verbe, pour vérifier : *"j'ai peur qu'il fasse"*, parfait, nous avons ici notre subjonctif.

Le verbe avoir, dans la proposition *"son interlocuteur [avoir] pour dessein de l'énerver"*, dépend de *"il pense"*.

Il est vrai que l'on peut parfois utiliser un subjonctif après le verbe penser, mais cela indiquerait une opinion ou supposition peu probable (par exemple, *"je ne pense pas qu'il y soit déjà" = "je doute qu'il y soit déjà"*, ou * "je ne pense pas qu'il fait ses devoirs" = "cela m'étonnerait qu'il ait fait ses devoirs"*

Ici, nous avons une déclaration ferme : *"j'ai peur de ceci"*, cela ne fonctionnerait donc pas.

Le verbe avoir ne prendra donc pas de subjonctif. Votre exemple sera ainsi conjugué :

J'**ai** peur qu'il **pense** que son interlocuteur **a** pour dessein de l'énerver.

Comment: C'était aussi mon analyse personnelle dans le cas d'une situation présente. Pour une situation envisagée : « j'ai peur que (plus tard) il pense que … », j'avoue que le subjonctif ne me gêne pas, mais je ne sais pas l'expliquer. J'envisage l'existence d'un phénomène plus subtil que l'imbrication de deux constructions à mode fixe. C'est pourquoi je cherche des références ou des statistiques qui révèleraient un phénomène caché. En tout cas merci d'avoir précisé tout ça, ça confirme une première intuition que je ne voulais pas ajouter pour laisser la question ouverte.