# Le dilemme du subjonctif! Où se place-t-il quand il y a deux verbes ?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, subordonnées, mode-grammatical

Laquelle de ces phrases est correcte?

1. Je ne pense pas qu'il y **ait** quelqu'un qui **puisse** faire ça.
2. Je ne pense pas qu'il y **a** quelqu'un qui **puisse** faire ça.
3. Je ne pense pas qu'il y **ait** quelqu'un qui **peut** faire ça.
4. Je ne pense pas qu'il y **a** quelqu'un qui **peut** faire ça.

*Existerait*-il des sémantiques qui *puissent* être exprimées par chacune de ces phrases?

Comment: Pour la phrase suggérée, on pourrait simplement dire "Je ne pense pas que quelqu'un puisse le faire". La question reste valide cependant !

Comment: @Kii, effectivement! Je n'ai pas besoin de cette phrase, j'étais simplement curieux, mais en effet, je peux toujours la contorsionner pour trouver une façon d'éviter le dilemme :) En parlant avec un linguiste il semblerait qu'il puisse y avoir "une charge sémantique différente" à chacune des trois premières phrases, mais on est pas arrivé à trouver ce qu'elle pourraient exprimer.

Comment: Question similaire: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11553/les-sous-subordonn%c3%a9es-h%c3%a9ritent-elles-du-mode-subjonctif

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, en effet elle y ressemble, mais ce n'est pas tout à fait la même chose. À dire vrai, en lisant votre question et sa réponse, je penche vers un subjonctif dans les deux verbes (donc 1) parce que "avoir" est subordonné à "penser que" mais "pouvoir" n'est pas dans ce cas... Si? Plus précisément, je pense aussi que chacune des trois premières phrases *peut* avoir un sens bien à elle, subtilement différent des deux autres (excluons la 4 qui est, je pense, fausse). Mais je me trompe peut-être...

Answer (score 1):

je pense que grammaticalement, seule la première est correcte. Maintenant en "parlé oral quotidien", on maltraite souvent la grammaire, en particulier le subjonctif.

Answer (score 0):

**Avec un sens affirmatif** - on en est assez sûr:

> Je ne pense pas qu'il y a quelqu'un qui peut faire ça.

**Avec un sens hypothétique** (on doute), les deux semblent assez équivalentes.

> Je ne pense pas qu'il y a quelqu'un qui puisse faire ça.
>
> Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait quelqu'un qui puisse faire ça.

Toutefois, la première - qui démarre de manière affirmative, affiche une certaine assurance, pour finir par un subjonctif, cela suggère *Je pense qu'il y a quelqu'un qui peut faire autre chose, mais pas **ça**.*

**Celle-ci est plutôt moins utilisée**: des gens pour faire cela, cela existe, mais il n'y en a pas (ici ?):

> Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait quelqu'un qui peut faire ça.

**En revanche, on pourrait aussi utiliser le conditionnel:**

> Je ne pense pas qu'il y a quelqu'un qui pourrait faire cela.

**Si on emploie le conditionnel dans la première relative**, on n'est plus dans le présent:

> Je ne pense pas qu'il y aurait quelqu'un qui pourrait faire cela.

: double hypothèse, dans le futur ou une autre situation.

Comment: Aurais-tu quelques sources ?