# Je déteste penser que + subjonctif?

Tags: subjonctif

On dit:

- je déteste que tu sois indifférent (subjonctif)
- je pense que tu es indifférent (indicatif)

Qu'en est-il de "je déteste penser que tu **es/sois** indifférent"? Quelle est la bonne forme, subjonctif ou indicatif?

Comment: Les deux se disent mais le sens est différent. [Cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11574/358) te permet-elle de résoudre ton interrogation ? Sinon pour t'aider il faut donner plus de contexte à la situation pour indiquer quel degré de certitude a le locuteur sur cette « différence ».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La bonne forme dépend de ce dont on parle et de la forme de l'énoncé, soit la forme affirmative soit la forme négative.

> ([La Culture Générale](https://www.laculturegenerale.com/penser-que-mode-infinitif-subjonctif-conditionnel/))
>
> 1. À la forme affirmative, cette locution peut être suivie de l’indicatif, du conditionnel (surtout à l’interrogatif) ou de l’infinitif. [Le subjonctif se trouve aussi.]
> 2. À la forme négative, cette locution peut être suivie du subjonctif (le mode du doute, du virtuel, et quand « on ne pense pas que », on doute, on suppose, on est dans le virtuel), de l’indicatif, du conditionnel ou de l’infinitif.

Si on parle de l'indifférence en tant que possibilité, alors le subjonctif convient, ou le conditionnel (mais ce dernier mode est moins courant et d'un registre plus formel).

- Je déteste penser que tu sois/serais indifférent.
- Je déteste penser que tu es indifférent. (*Le présent peut être utilisé, mais il n'exprime pas clairement que la personne qui parle ne croit pas de prime abord à l'indifférence de celle à qui elle parle.*)

([réf. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Vie_d_Adrien_Zograffi/K5pMAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22penser+que+tu+sois%22&dq=%22penser+que+tu+sois%22&printsec=frontcover)) Or, ajouta-t-il malicieusement , je ne veux pas te faire l'injure de penser que tu sois dépourvu de cette conscience que tout homme éclairé doit avoir de son rôle dans l'histoire des évolutions de la société humaine

([réf. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_chemin_de_cr%C3%AAte/kgVYxmgX2m8C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22penser+que+tu+serais%22&dq=%22penser+que+tu+serais%22&printsec=frontcover)) Je te faisais l'honneur de penser que tu serais assez raisonnable pour comprendre quelle aubaine représentait pour toi l'amitié d'un homme comme Bassigny

([réf. 3](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_Coupe_Stainless/RtxWAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22penser+que+tu+serais%22&dq=%22penser+que+tu+serais%22&printsec=frontcover)) Rien qu'à penser que tu serais dans la cave du classement, j'en ferais une dépression...

Si on parle de l'indifférence comme quelque chose de confirmé, le présent est le temps qui convient.

- Je déteste penser que tu es indifférent.

([réf. 4](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Avec_un_chromosome_de_plus/hTvfCwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22penser+que+tu+es%22&pg=PT30&printsec=frontcover)) J'ai même du mal à penser que tu es vivant. Tu veux que je sois sincère ? Tu n'es pas né hier.

([réf. 5](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Oeuvres_compl%C3%A8tes/6qwNAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22penser+que+tu+es%22&dq=%22penser+que+tu+es%22&printsec=frontcover)) Cela réjouit mon vieux cœur, Lorenzo, de penser que tu es honnête ; alors tu jetteras ce déguisement hideux qui te défigure, et tu redeviendras d'un métal aussi pur que les statues de bronze d'Harmodius et d'Aristogiton".

Comment: Bonne analyse, en effet le subjonctif semble rajouter le bénéfice du doute.

Answer (score 1):

***Je déteste penser*** est une phrase grammaticalement correcte mais qui ne « sonne pas très juste ».

Il s'agit très probablement d'un anglicisme, d'un calque de ***I hate to think*** comme peut le laisser supposer son émergence assez récente :

[image]
Suivant le sens désiré, on pourra plutôt utiliser :

- Ça me rend malade/me révulse de penser que...
- Je ne veux pas croire que...
- Je n'ose pas penser/imaginer que...
- Ça me dégoute que...
- ...

Dans l'exemple de la question, ce pourrait être :

> **Je** n'ose pas / **ne veux pas croire** que tu **puisses** être indifférent. (registre soutenu + doute)

> **Ça me rend malade de savoir** que tu **es** indifférent. (registre courant + certitude)

Answer (score 0):

Dans "je déteste penser que tu es/sois indifférent", "que tu es/sois indifférent" est est associé à "penser" et non "déteste". Je ne déteste pas l'indifference, je déteste ce que tu pense. Alors, l'indicatif est le meilleur mode.